# I wrote some jquery, html and php code for e-mail form contact but something is wrong

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

I wrote a code in html, php and jquery in order to be able to make e-mail form on a web site.

However, some problems occurred while testing:

1) problem with validations: in my jquery code, in order to prevent submitting the form before it checks if all the fields are ok, I put ~ e.preventDefault(); ~ insde the jquery code.
Then if I try to submit the form, the script will check if the fields are ok and show errors inside input fields for inputs which are not ok. And, offcourse, it wont send the mail.
But, if I fill all the fields correctly, It won't send the mail either.

2) on the other hand, if I remove the above mentioned ~ e.preventDefault(); ~ code, than the script bypasses field validation checks and sends alerts (for the fields not correctly written) through the Exception alert messages.

3) if all other fields are correctly filled, the script requires the attachment to be sent as well. How to prevent that.

Please help, obviously I made some mistakes inside the code.

My code is:

HTML code:

```
<form id="kontakt_obrazac" name="kontakt_obrazac" method="POST" action="php/kontakt.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li id="ime"><input type="text" name="ime" placeholder="Ime i prezime" id="input_ime" /></li>
        <li id="mail"><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Mail" id="input_mail" /></li>
        <li id="naslov"><input type="text" name="naslov" placeholder="Naslov" id="input_naslov" /></li>
        <li id="poruka"><textarea name="poruka" placeholder="Poruka" id="input_poruka"></textarea></li>
        <li id="file"><input type="file" name="attachment" value="" id="input_file" /></li>
        <li id="posalji"><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Pošalji" class="submit_btn" /></li>
        <li id="ponisti"><input type="reset" name="reset_btn" value="Poništi" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
/* Namespace alias. */
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/* Include the Composer generated autoload.php file. */
require 'C:\xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';

/* Create a new PHPMailer object. Passing TRUE to the constructor enables exceptions. */
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

/* Open try/catch block. */
try
{
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
{

    $user_name = $_POST['ime'];
    $user_mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $subject = $_POST['naslov'];
    $message = $_POST['poruka'];


    /* Set the mail sender. */
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['mail'], $_POST['ime']);

    /* Add a recipient. */
    $mail->addAddress('nebojsano@gmail.com');

    /* Set the subject. */
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['naslov'];

    /* Set the mail message body. */
    $mail->Body = ($_POST['poruka']);


    /* SMTP parameters. */

    /* Tells PHPMailer to use SMTP. */
    $mail->isSMTP();

    /* SMTP server address. */
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    /* Use SMTP authentication. */
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    /* Set the encryption system. */
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    /* SMTP authentication username. */
    $mail->Username = 'nebojsano@gmail.com';

    /* SMTP authentication password. */
    $mail->Password = 'mmajke';

    /* Set the SMTP port. */
    $mail->Port = 587;


    /* Add an attachment */
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name']);

    /* Set a reply-to address */
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['mail'], $_POST['ime']);

    /* Add CC and BCC recipients */
    // $mail->addCC('stones2n@hotmail.com');


    /* Enable SMTP debug output. */
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

    /* Disable some SSL checks. */
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
          )
       );

    /* Finally send the mail. */
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        echo "Problem in Sending Mail.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Mail Sent.";
    }

}
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

JQUERY code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#kontakt_obrazac').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var ime = $('#input_ime').val();
        var mail = $('#input_mail').val();
        var naslov = $('#input_naslov').val();
        var poruka = $('#input_poruka').val();
        var attachment = $('#input_file').val();

        $(".error").remove();

        if (ime.length < 1) {
            $('#input_ime').css({color: "#ff0000"});
            $('#input_ime').css({border: "1px solid #ff0000"});
            $('#input_ime').attr('placeholder', 'Obavezno polje');
        } else {
            $('#input_ime').css({color: "#006600"});
            $('#input_ime').css({border: "none"});
        }

        if (mail.length < 1) {
            $('#input_mail').css({color: "#ff0000"});
            $('#input_mail').css({border: "1px solid #ff0000"});
            $('#input_mail').attr('placeholder', 'Obavezno polje');
        } else {
            var reg_ex = /^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Za-z]{2,63}$/;
            var valid_mail = reg_ex.test(mail);
            if (valid_mail) {
                $('#input_mail').css({color: "#006600"});
                $('#input_mail').css({border: "none"});
            } else {
                $('#input_mail').css({color: "#ff0000"});
                $('#input_mail').css({border: "1px solid #ff0000"});
            }
        }

        if (naslov.length < 1) {
            $('#input_naslov').css({color: "#ff0000"});
            $('#input_naslov').css({border: "1px solid #ff0000"});
            $('#input_naslov').attr('placeholder', 'Obavezno polje');
        } else {
            $('#input_naslov').css({color: "#006600"});
            $('#input_naslov').css({border: "none"});
        }

        if (poruka.length < 1) {
            $('#input_poruka').css({color: "#ff0000"});
            $('#input_poruka').attr('placeholder', 'Obavezno polje');
        } else {
            $('#input_poruka').css({color: "green"});
        }

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery code when you do the preventDefault, at the end of your validation you can return false if the validation failed, and return true to continue the post of the form.
Not sure what you mean with your 3rd problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try that. With the third problem I mean that for now if I don't chose a file to be attched the script returns error message: "Could not access file:", which means that the file is considered required. But I do not want the file to be required like other fields. Can you help?

Comment: It works for me if I place this down at the end of the JavaScript file (inside the onClick)
return $('.error').length <= 0;
Also use this check in your html before you add the attachment:
if ( ! empty($_FILES)) {...}